# Getting values from list which only exist once in C#

Tags: c#, list

i have a problem with a C# int-List.
For example I have 7 values `(12, 65, 312, 52, 312, 85, 14)` in the list. It is possible that values are present more than once (In this case it is the value 312).

The first thing is, that I sort the List with 'list.Sort()'.
Then my goal is, that I get a new list with every value that only existed once. In this case the new list would be `(12, 14, 52, 65, 85)`.

I don't understand how I could do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use Linq...

```
var newList = new List<int>() { 12, 65, 312, 52, 312, 85, 14 }
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: You'll still need to order the values, if that's what OP wants for the new list.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!

Is there also a possibility how I can only save the values which come more often?

Comment: @xileb0 what do you mean by `which come more often`?

Comment: For example in this case, there should be 312 the only number in the list. because it is the only one, that is not "single".

Comment: @xileb0 you can use a different condition like `.Where(x => x.Count() > 1)`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var intList = new List<int>() { 12, 65, 312, 52, 312, 85, 14 };
var filtered = intList.Where(x => intList.Count(z => z == x) == 1).OrderBy(x => x);

foreach(int i in filtered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);   
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gjI0i8)

Answer (score 0):

Just some additional info, I was looking for the same solution. However I wanted to query a collection of objects on one property(Filename)...and return the correct objects into the list...

```
queryDatabase.GroupBy(x => x.Filename).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```